# How to use ApolloQuery Vue component to query an Elasticsearch endpoint?

Tags: elasticsearch, nuxt.js, apollo-client

I use Apollo Client on my Nuxt projects to query GraphQL endpoints and it works great. But now, I need to query an Elasticsearch endpoint on AWS. How would I query this endpoint using my existing Apollo client?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not query the ElasticSearch directly from your Vue component. You should query your ApolloGraph Server that will query your ElasticSearch end point and return the result from that query.

You can query the Elasticsearch from inside your resolver. The ApolloGraphQL resolver accepts an promise as result and will wait for this promise get resolved.

If you have a resolver like this:

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    user(parent, args, context, info) {
        let bar = args.id; 
        return queryElasticSearch(bar)
    }
  }
}
```

(For reference: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/)

The ElasticSearch have this client wich you can connect to query your endpoint: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/client-usage.html

and in queryElasticSearch you can have something like this:

```
async function queryElasticSearch(bar){
   const result = await client.search({
   index: 'my-index',
   body: { foo: bar }
  })
  return result;
}
```